# "App" has unfortunately stopped working caused by "could not find method android.view.Window$Callback" errors

Tags: java, android, xml

I am building a mobile app for my project on which I have to retrieve data sent to Thingspeak on it.

[image: This is the mobile app interface:]
When I tap on an image button, it should open a new activity which will show its last value retrieved from Thingspeak.

The issue I am getting is that the app stops working when I click on an image button which is supposed to bring me to another activity. It does open a new activity showing that navigation to another activity is working but then it shows "Smart Agriculture has unfortunately stopped working". I think the problem is in the `xml` files of the activities or the `TextView` I have used in some `TempHumidity.java` file but I don't really know how to resolve them being an absolute beginner in Android Studio.  I have 5 files namely `activity_main.xml`, `MainActivity.java`, `TempHumidity.java`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, `imgbtnmenu.xml`

`TempHumidity.java` class(it contains the HttpURLConnection codes)

```
public class TempHumidity extends AppCompatActivity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imgbtnmenu);
    new GetMethodDemo().execute("https://thingspeak.com/channels/357670/field/1/last");

}
public class GetMethodDemo extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;
    private TextView aTextView;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);
        aTextView.setText(s);


    }
}

 // Converting InputStream to String

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response.toString();
   }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.teerna.smartagriculture">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TempHumidity">      // you need to add these 3 lines inside application tag.
    </activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

`imgbtnmenu.xml` for the new activity menu(the menu that opens when Humidity and Temperature image button is tapped)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

The messages on Logcat are as follows:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next time post your logcat as text !

Comment: @nhoxbypass When I am posting the logcat as text, it is exceeding the max word limit for body text on StackOverflow.

Comment: Most of them is only warning, could you give me the full line which contain `android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable`

Comment: `Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`

Comment: I've posted the answer, please try it, if not work I will find another way for you!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the logcat is only warning, you can see the `W/` character. The The app crashes because you're receiving a `java.lang.VerifyError` which is `Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable`. This error will only happen on pre-lolipop device (Android 5.0)

Try add these line to build.gradle:

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

If it still not working, change `app:srcCompat` inside every ImageView to `android:src`

Comment: Thanks.. That line `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` was already in the gradle actually. And I made the change that you suggested but the same errors still persist. And I updated my codes by adding ` aTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);` and creating a TextView of id `textView` in the `imgbtnmenu.xml` file. The errors which pertained to the `TextView` have disappeared while maintaining the rest. The app no longer showed the error that it has stopped once I had instantiated the TextView actually. Then I considered the change you suggested. The errors still maintained.

Comment: The new activity is not able to retrieve any value. Am I missing something out in the codes?

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild after change as I suggest?

Comment: I restarted Android Studio, uninstalled and rebuilt the app but still no value was retrieved. I suppose it has something to do with the URL. I probably should use Json to retrieve the values. I am now working on that.

Comment: Can you please check it again? The same errors seem to persist and the app has again started to stop upon onclick of an image button

Comment: Did you use LayerDrawable or VectorDrawable (which contain <selector>, <vector> tag), and I saw that your `aTextView` is not initialize, not call `findViewById`

Comment: Am restarting the coding of the project all over. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160915/discussion-between-margo-roth-spiegelman-and-nhoxbypass).